# Closing a QDialog and disconnect signals fails

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I need to open a `QDialog` in a different class of the `QMainWindow`, and after closing the `QDialog`, all the signals must be disconnected.

I can open the `QDialog` by pressing a combination of keys and then, when it is open instantly is connected to the `button_pressed`method which itself is connected to `self.spanSelector_press` and `self.spanSelector_`

This is the code so far:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):    #This is a matplotlib figure
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    #A lot of stuff for the matplotlib figure

  def button_pressed(self):
    self.select_data = SelectData(self)
    self.select_data.show()

    self.cid_press = self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',
       self.spanSelector_press)
    self.cid_release = self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event',
       self.spanSelector_release)

  def spanSelector_press(self, event):
    if event.button ==1:
        self.limite = "minimum"
        self.clearMarker()  #This is another method to erase the previous line drawn

        self.marker = self.axes.axvline(Window.minimumCoords, linestyle='dashed',
            linewidth = 2, color = "green") 

        self.figure_canvas.draw_idle()
        Window.initial_marker = self.marker

        self.xmin = event.xdata

  def spanSelector_release(self, event):
    pass

class SelectData(QDialog):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    QDialog.__init__(self, parent, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)


  def closeEvent(self, event):
    #I need to disconnect all the signals when i close the QDialog

    view = self.parent()
    view.figure_canvas.mpl_disconnect(view.cid_press)
    view.figure_canvas.mpl_disconnect(view.cid_release)
    view.deselect()
    event.accept()
```

How can i disconnect all the signals in the `button_pressed` method after closing the `QDialog`? Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#event-connections) you can disconnect using the connection id, which you'll need to save by doing something like this in `Window`:

```
def button_pressed(self):
    self.select_data = SelectData(self)
    self.select_data.show()
    self.cid_press = self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.spanSelector_press)
    self.cid_release = self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.spanSelector_release)
```

Your `SelectData` class has a reference to its parent class (`Window`) that can be had by calling `parent()`, so you can use that to do the disconnection.

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    window = self.parent()
    window.figure_canvas.mpl_disconnect(window.cid_press)
    window.figure_canvas.mpl_disconnect(window.cid_release)
    event.accept()
```

I haven't tested that, but it should be pretty close.

**Edit:** be sure to pass `parent` to `QDialog` constructor as such:

```
class SelectData(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

Comment: Thnak you for you answer. No, it does not work. I tried this and it gives me an error that says: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'figure_canvas'`.

Comment: Oops, the `parent()` call is not returning the parent, see my edit to fix that.

Comment: I edited the code and i added the `spanSelector_press` method to show it. I tried and added your solution, but it still fails when i tried to disconnect. Sorry for bothering you, and thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It does not connect at all when i do this, and of course, it does not disconnect either.